# Counting the comparisons in quicksort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need help counting the number of compares done by these function please. I have already declared a variable compCount that stores the amount of comparisons but please help figure out where to place the compCount++ incrementors.

I understand the you place count incrementors when you do a .compare function but there are complicated loops like this one:

```
for (i = low, j = high - 1;;) {
            
            while (a[++i].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                
            }
            
            while (pivot.compareTo(a[--j]) < 0) {
                
            }
            
            if (i >= j) {
                break;
            }
            
            swapReferences(a, i, j);
        }
```

And also in the insertionSort() function

Here is the code:

```
public class QuickSort implements Sort {
long compCount;

/**
 * Quicksort algorithm.
 * 
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void QuickSort(Comparable[] a) {
    compCount = 0;
    sort(a);
}

private static final int CUTOFF = 10;

/**
 * Method to swap to elements in an array.
 * 
 * @param a      an array of objects.
 * @param index1 the index of the first object.
 * @param index2 the index of the second object.
 */
public static void swapReferences(Object[] a, int index1, int index2) {
    Object tmp = a[index1];
    a[index1] = a[index2];
    a[index2] = tmp;
}

/**
 * Internal quicksort method that makes recursive calls. Uses median-of-three
 * partitioning and a cutoff of 10.
 * 
 * @param a    an array of Comparable items.
 * @param low  the left-most index of the subarray.
 * @param high the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private void quicksort(Comparable[] a, int low, int high) {
    if (low + CUTOFF > high)
        insertionSort(a, low, high);
    else {
        // Sort low, middle, high
        
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (a[middle].compareTo(a[low]) < 0) {
            
            swapReferences(a, low, middle);
        }
        if (a[high].compareTo(a[low]) < 0) {
            
            swapReferences(a, low, high);
        }
        if (a[high].compareTo(a[middle]) < 0) {
            
            swapReferences(a, middle, high);
        }
        // Place pivot at position high - 1
        swapReferences(a, middle, high - 1);
        Comparable pivot = a[high - 1];

        // Begin partitioning
        int i, j;
        for (i = low, j = high - 1;;) {
            
            while (a[++i].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                
            }
            
            while (pivot.compareTo(a[--j]) < 0) {
                
            }
            
            if (i >= j) {
                break;
            }
            
            swapReferences(a, i, j);
        }

        // Restore pivot
        swapReferences(a, i, high - 1);

        quicksort(a, low, i - 1); // Sort small elements
        quicksort(a, i + 1, high); // Sort large elements
    }
}

/**
 * Internal insertion sort routine for subarrays that is used by quicksort.
 * 
 * @param a   an array of Comparable items.
 * @param low the left-most index of the subarray.
 * @param n   the number of items to sort.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private void insertionSort(Comparable[] a, int low, int high) {
    for (int p = low + 1; p <= high; p++) {
        Comparable tmp = a[p];
        int j;
        
        for (j = p; j > low && tmp.compareTo(a[j - 1]) < 0; j--) {
            
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        }
        
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void sort(Comparable[] a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    compCount = 0;
    quicksort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

@Override
public long getCompares() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return compCount;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, perhaps count when compareTo is called?

Comment: You will need to place `compCount++` inside each while loop (to account for each time compare is less than 0) and after each while loop (to account for the 1 time compare is not less than 0).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out thanks to my friend. Turns out you are supposed to count the compares outside the if statement not inside, and there are also some conditions I missed:

Here is the code:

```
public class QuickSort implements Sort {
long compCount;

/**
 * Quicksort algorithm.
 * 
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void QuickSort(Comparable[] a) {
    compCount = 0;
    sort(a);
}

private static final int CUTOFF = 10;

/**
 * Method to swap to elements in an array.
 * 
 * @param a      an array of objects.
 * @param index1 the index of the first object.
 * @param index2 the index of the second object.
 */
public static void swapReferences(Object[] a, int index1, int index2) {
    Object tmp = a[index1];
    a[index1] = a[index2];
    a[index2] = tmp;
}

/**
 * Internal quicksort method that makes recursive calls. Uses median-of-three
 * partitioning and a cutoff of 10.
 * 
 * @param a    an array of Comparable items.
 * @param low  the left-most index of the subarray.
 * @param high the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private void quicksort(Comparable[] a, int low, int high) {
    if (low + CUTOFF > high) {
        insertionSort(a, low, high);
    }
    else {
        // Sort low, middle, high
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        
        if (a[middle].compareTo(a[low]) < 0) {
            swapReferences(a, low, middle); 
        }
        compCount++;
        if (a[high].compareTo(a[low]) < 0) {
            swapReferences(a, low, high);
        }
        compCount++;
        if (a[high].compareTo(a[middle]) < 0) {
            swapReferences(a, middle, high);    
        }
        compCount++;
        // Place pivot at position high - 1
        swapReferences(a, middle, high - 1);
        Comparable pivot = a[high - 1];

        // Begin partitioning
        int i, j;
        for (i = low, j = high - 1;;) {
            
            while (a[++i].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                compCount++;
            }
            compCount++;
            while (pivot.compareTo(a[--j]) < 0) {
                compCount++;
            }
            compCount++;
            if (i >= j) {
                break;
            }
            
            swapReferences(a, i, j);
        }

        // Restore pivot
        swapReferences(a, i, high - 1);

        quicksort(a, low, i - 1); // Sort small elements
        quicksort(a, i + 1, high); // Sort large elements
    }
}

/**
 * Internal insertion sort routine for subarrays that is used by quicksort.
 * 
 * @param a   an array of Comparable items.
 * @param low the left-most index of the subarray.
 * @param n   the number of items to sort.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private void insertionSort(Comparable[] a, int low, int high) {
    for (int p = low + 1; p <= high; p++) {
        Comparable tmp = a[p];
        int j;
        for (j = p; j > low && tmp.compareTo(a[j - 1]) < 0; j--) {
            compCount++;
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        }
        
        if(j > low)
            compCount++;
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void sort(Comparable[] a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    compCount = 0;
    quicksort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

@Override
public long getCompares() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return compCount;
}
```

}